# ActionResult not picking up parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, routes

URL:

```
http://localhost:49917/Home/CreateInsured/16
```

policyID is null:

```
// GET: Policy/CreateInsured
[Route("Home/CreateInsured/{policyID}")]
public ActionResult CreateInsured(string policyID)
{
    .... logic ...
    return View();
}
```

Pretty sure I will kick myself when I see the answer

Comment: change string to int

Comment: If that's all I do, I get a null reference error.  So if I make it (int policyID?) it does't throw an error, but it still comes up null

Comment: if you are calling it from javascript use the same name and if you are using    @Html.ActionLink then use it like this @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { policyID=item.id})

Comment: @rashfmnb why would you presume this? He's just typing the url in manually (I hope, seen as he hasn't shown an actionlink)

Comment: Just throwing a guess out here, because I don't know if it's possible, but could another route somewhere be getting used instead of the one shown??

Comment: do you have regiatered attribute routes in config like: ``routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`` in ``RegisterRoutes`` method

Comment: see here : http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-mvc-5-attribute-routing

Comment: Sorry... I'm not following. Can you post an answer with example syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Assume for now I'm just hitting the URL directly in a browser, no javascript

Comment: What happens if you specify the parameter name, like: http://localhost:49917/Home/CreateInsured?policyID=16

Comment: @JamesR. --  it threw an ugly error: Dangerous stuff in the URL (don't recall exact text of the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to do this replace this with

```
[Route("Home/CreateInsured/{policyID}")]
```

this

```
[Route("Home/CreateInsured/{id}")]
```

and change the name of parameter in Method as well

Answer (score 0):

Why does the autogenerated comment say // GET: Policy/CreateInsured.  Could it be that the controller name is Policy instead of Home?

Comment: Ignore the auto generated comments.  They are not correct.  (long story)

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
[Route("Home/CreateInsured/{policyID}")]
```

because your "RouteConfig.cs" has route configured by default, i.e.

```
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

so use this instead:

```
public ActionResult CreateInsured(string id)
{
    .... logic ...
    return View();
}
```